# ListView rendering error on GetX's Get.defaultDialog and Get.dialog

Tags: listview, dialog, flutter-getx

If we use Flutter's default AlertDialog and showDialog, we don't encounter any issues with the ListView wrap.

```
return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Title of Dialog"),
              content: SizedBox(
                width: double.minPositive, 
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true, 
                  ...
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    ...
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
```

The problem comes when we use Dialog from **GetX**, are *Get.defaultDialog* or *Get.dialog*. While debugging, an error message appears: *"Cannot hit test a render box with no size.'* The error can be removed by adding a size height and width for example:

```
content: SizedBox(
         width: 300,
         heights: 300,
...
)
```

But the problem is not finished, because ***a lot of empty space*** will appear, where the contents of the ListView are *smaller than all the widgets* in the Dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem using this way:

I wrapped the `ListView.Builder()` in `Flexible` and then I wrapped `Flexible` In `Column` widget with `MainaxisSize` property set to **Minimium**.

Here's the example code you can try:

```js
Get.dialog(
        Center(
          child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              width: 200,
              color: Colors.amber,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: 30,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                          return Center(
                            child: Text("demo"),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
```

If the `itemcount` is less then it will shrink the dialog too.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helped you out. If so, I would appreciate it if you could Accept my answer If you still have questions, feel free to ask. In the end, it's always about the community 